# Drop down list only showing [Object Object]

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code it works sfine the problem the dropdown list only shows [object object]
how do i go about fixing this error.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#RepfocusModelDropdown").change(function () {
        var Id = $(this).val();
        if (Id != null) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./Create?handler=UserSelect",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                data: {
                    Id: Id
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#Repfocususerdropdown").empty();
                    alert(response);
                    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                        $("#Repfocususerdropdown").append("<option>" + { value: item.Name, text: item.Name } + "</option>");

                    });
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }

            });

        }


    })
})
```

Comment: Your `<option>`s contain object literals; if Objects are forcibly converted to strings, that's what you get. Use `.append("<option>" + item.Name + "</option>")`, since the content will be used as value if no value is provided.

Comment: My only guess is `item.Name` isn't a string, but is instead, an object. What is the exact output in the DOM from this code? That would help understand the problem.

Comment: `[object object]` means you tried to force a complex object into a string context - and that is exactly what you are doing with `"<option>" + { value: item.Name, text: item.Name } + "</option>"`. Trying to use this kind of string concatenation does not make sense here to begin with. You need to set the value attribute and the text content of the option separately.

Comment: You can parse the `json reponse` and check.

Comment: Compare: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/6Ljg8uqe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code inside success function:

```
var user = $('#Repfocususerdropdown').empty(), opt = null;
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
    opt = $('<option/>', {"text": item.Name, "value": i});
    user.append(opt);
});
```